# React Native + FFProbe + FFMpeg

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ffmpeg, ffprobe

Is it possible to use FFmpeg or FFprobe inside a react native app for interacting with a video stream? I see an FFprobe package published to npm but it's only Node.js compatible: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffprobe

Comment: Not sure if ffprobe can be used, but you won't have success with ffmpeg, at least with node packages. Here is a complete ffmpeg library for node: https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg. But you need to install ffmpeg natively. On windows or linux no problem, but android or ios?! There are libraries for the mobile platforms, but to interact with them, you will need to use the native SDKs.